# Assert.Inconclusive() tests in ccnet fail the build

Tags: c#, mstest, ccnet-config

I am having a visual studio 2010 test harness which tests different endpoints(applications) for the same test, and when run for all endpoints some tests don't run against the endpoint and returns as an inconclusive test which in turn fails the build.Using mstest/ccnet for continuous integration is there a way to make the build pass but still display the count of inconclusive test.

I went through [this](http://blog.dbtracer.org/2011/02/27/inconclusive-tests-in-tfs-build-should-not-break-the-build/) blog but was not able to work for ccnet projects by changing the proj. file.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be to run msbuild and mstest separately. So you have your tasks

```
<task>
<msbuild>
<executable>c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe</executable>
<workingDirectory>youWorkinDir</workingDirectory>
<projectFile>yourProjd.proj</projectFile>
<targets>Build</targets>
</msbuild>
<exec>
<executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe</executable>
<buildArgs>/testcontainer:YourTestProject.dll /resultsfile:TestResult.xml</buildArgs>
</exec>
</task>
```

In publisher section, before `</xmllogger>` you have a merge task, that will include output file in build log:

```
<publishers>
<merge>
 <files>
   <file>TestResult.xml</file>
 </files>
</merge>
</publishers>
```